# Updating chart format

Tags: python, seaborn

I would like to change this from a line of regression to a curve. Also to have the line reach either side of the graph. Here is my code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Days':  [5, 10, 15, 20],
        'Impact': [33.7561, 30.6281, 29.5748, 29.0482]
        }

a = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Days','Impact'])

print (a)

ax = sns.barplot(data=a, x='Days', y='Impact', color='lightblue' )
# put bars in background:
for c in ax.patches:
    c.set_zorder(0)
# plot regplot with numbers 0,..,len(a) as x value

ax = sns.regplot(x=np.arange(0,len(a)), y=a['Impact'], marker="+")
sns.despine(offset=10, trim=False)
ax.set_ylabel("")
ax.set_xticklabels(['5', '10','15','20'])
plt.show()
```

Alternatively, I would prefer to do it in matplotlib as a scatter plot instead of bar chart. Here is an example in excel, but ideally to have the curve extend beyond the outside markers at least a little.

[image: Example image with short curve line]

Can anyone help?

Comment: It is unclear what curve do you want here

Comment: Can you show an image of the expected result?

Comment: Try `Implot` instead `regplot`.: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html